# Java how to find out required libaries download them and then run the program?

Tags: java, jar

After using eclipse i decided to ask this what bugs me the most. When exporting a project to working .jar you have 3 options. Because using extract or package required libraries into jars gives my program a lot of space to have than 3 options, copy required libraries to directory. Now my project has only about 70 kb than 15 mb before. Actually i didn't recognize that not possessing folder with my library classes cause some issues. Why?

I heard from a friend of mine that some thing were not working for him and i send him only jar, than lib. 
Is there a difference between exporting types and machines( i poses jdk my friend not only jre)?

Is there a way to check for required essentials libraries or class that are required, check on system and order to download them? Or just download the external lib folder. The most i am interested in detecting missing classes or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to learn some things but you may want to try using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) projects. Maven is a Java building tool. One of Maven's most important features is [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).

Comment: Still it doesnt solve my question. Req libaries are in classpath. Eclipse set claspath to basefileExportName as dir. Now i want to download the dir that i have link for..